# Comparing combo box date to datadable box

Tags: vb.net, date, datatable, combobox, compare

My comparison is slightly different than the usual comparison between a combo box and a value in a data table, which I have done before. I compared strings.

But in this situation if the selected date in the combo box is Jan 1, 2018; I need to check if the first date (in the date column) in the data table is Jan 2, 2018. If the date in the data table is anything but one day after the selected date in the combo box, it should produce an error, a pop up error or something like that.

The verification is to be 1 day AFTER what is in the combo box.

Is there a method in comparing dates that follow a certain date? date + 1? something like this?

Comment: Are you looking for `DateTime.AddDays(int)`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just compare the two dates to each other (see [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2).  The result will be a a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2) object which has a `Days` property which you can check to see if it is 1 or not.

```
Dim day1 As New Date(2008, 1, 1)
Dim day2 As New Date(2008, 1, 2)

Dim result As TimeSpan = day2 - day1

Console.WriteLine("Number of Days: {0}", result.Days)
```

Your other option would be to get the date from the combo box and add a day to it and then check if the dates are equal.  For this you can use the [AddDays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.

```
Dim day1 As New Date(2008, 1, 1)
Dim day2 As Date = day1.AddDays(1)
```

*Edit*
Since you asked about parsing from a string.  You need to use the [Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) parsing functions (either `Parse` or `TryParse`).

```
Dim date1 As Date
If Date.TryParse("2018-05-18", date1) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Date is {0}", date1)
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Couldn't parse")
End If
```

So rewriting the above example we would have something like this:

```
Dim day1 As Date

If Date.TryParse(comboBox.Text, day1) Then
    Dim dayPlus1 As Date = day1.AddDays(1)
    ' Compare with your database date here
Else
    'Handle the error case here
End If
```

Comment: I tried following your method. I tried assigning dim Date1 as new date(combobox.text)  combobox.text is the selected date in the combobox.... but it produced an error of "conversion from string "2018-05-18" to type 'Long' is not valid.

this is the same error I get when trying to get the value from the first box in column 1 in the data row.. so is new Date always type Long?

Comment: @user9990508 - From your question I assumed it was already a `Date` object. I have updated my answer to include parsing code.

Comment: I had used the method .substring to solve the issue, so now I am able to get the date from datatable box and store that into Date1 and date from combo box and store that into Date2. will use your method for .addDays and hopefully it works. thank you

Comment: @user9990508 - I am not sure how using `substring` is solving anything. What kind of data is in your combobox? If the combobox has a date/time string then you can just parse it into a date/time object. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve, can you show your code and an example of the data that is held in both the combobox and the datatable?

Comment: the substring method  was to solve the issue with regards to reading the contents in the datagridview boxes.it would take that content as a string "2018-05-18" and try to convert into a Long.So what I did was take a substring, and made that into a new date. and compared to the value in the combobox, since the value in the datagridview box had to be +1 day to the value in the combobox. 
the code;
`dim refStartDate as New Date (CLng(combobox.text.Substring(0,4)), (CLng(combobox.text.Substring(5, 2)), (CLng(combobox.text.Substring(8))`<br/>
then I used the method ".addDays()" to compare

Comment: @user9990508 - You absolutely should not use that code to get a `Date` object from the text. Just use the `Date.TryParse` method as I have shown in my answer. In your code you are taking a string object and creating 3 new string objects just so you can convert them to numbers and then pass those pieces of the date into the `Date` constructor, when you could accomplish the same goal by just passing the string you already have into the `Date.TryParse` method.

Comment: i see what you're saying. I am now using the date.tryparse, much cleaner. thank you